# Note boards in SharePoint 2010 for Team Sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, social-tag, team-sites

I've seen and used the note board functionality in SharePoint 2010.

I'm curious if anyone has any good information regarding doing team site updates using the note board. Also, If the system or user adds content to a site and we utilize the note board for updates -- can we prevent this content from showing up in everyone's my site activity feed - minus the users that have memberships to these team sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand that the Notes are considered "Social Data" or content and are not stored within the site.  The social data is stored centrally as part of the associated User Profile Service App and related databases, and only reference your site, page, or content.  When you put the Note Board Web part on the front page of a team site, it will show any notes for that page, but it is unique to the page and not the site as a whole.

If the page url were to change for example, the note board would actually appear to not have any notes until new ones are added.

With all of that in mind, since the notes are not site content but rather social data, the site's security trimming does not come into consideration and it would not be possible to prevent it from going through the activity feed without some sort of customization that filters the activity feed listener.

Comment: My intention is writing some custom code to allow this filtering. I've just seen nothing online, and trying to find a good resource to get me started.

Comment: I've not talked to anyone that has tried to do what you are proposing.